# How many seating arrangements are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

There are 7 employees (E) and 5 non-employees (NE). Four of them must be chosen to ride in a  four-seat vehicle. How many seating arrangments are possible if at least two passengers must be non-employes and only an employee can be the driver.

This is what I did:

The car has 4 seats: Right top (RT), left top (LT), right bottom (RB), left bottom (LB) - from a high-view perspective.

Case 1: RT: Employee, LT: Non-Employee, RB: Employee, LB: Non-Employee.

Hence, 7*5*6*4 = 840

Case 2: RT: Employee, LT: Non-Employee, RB: Non-Employee, LB: Employee.

Hence, 7*5*4*6 = 840

Case 3: RT: Employee, LT: Employee, RB: Non-Employee, LB: Non-Employee.

Hence, 7*6*5*4 = 840

Case 4: RT: Employee, LT: Non-Employee, RB: Non-Employee, LB: Non-Employee.

Hence, 7*5*4*3 = 420

840 + 840 + 840 + 420 = 2940.

So there are 2940 seating arrangments. Is my logic wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You solution looks good but you may shorten it a bit using some combinatorics:

- ways of choosing $1$ employee an $3$ non-employees: $\color{blue}{7\binom{5}{3}}$
- ways of seating them:  $\color{blue}{3!}$
- ways of choosing $2$ employee an $2$ non-employees: $\color{green}{\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}}$
- ways of seating them:$\color{green}{\underbrace{2}_{driver}\cdot 3!}$

All together:

$$\color{blue}{7\binom{5}{3}}\cdot \color{blue}{3!} + \color{green}{\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}}\cdot \color{green}{2\cdot 3!} = 2940$$